# how to avoid inserting duplicated rows working on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am working on pandas dataframe and mysql, my table is timeseries related like,

```
symbol_id  date     close
1          2016-6-1 123
1          2016-6-2 133
1          2016-6-3 143
2          2016-6-1 23
2          2016-6-2 33
2          2016-6-3 43
```

When asserting a new dataframe into the table, I use

```
df.to_sql(name='symbol_test1', con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index=True)
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you expecting and what results are you receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove duplicates, you can do something like this

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='symbol_id')
```

If you do not specify any subset parameter, then it by default checks for row level duplicates.

There are options to keep the first occurrence or last occurrence etc.
Please refer: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: does that mean I need to export the dataframe to python workspace and then dropping the duplicated after comparing with the expoted dataframe?

Comment: I am assuming the data that you mentioned in your question is already in a data frame. I do not understand what exactly you mean _"by dropping the duplicated after comparing with the expoted data frame?"_ @weiWu

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I haven't present my question clearly enough. The previous dataframe is stored in the mysql database, I need pull latest dataframe from the web and to store the latest one, this is what i mean.